# Guidelines on flagging obsolete comments

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

Many times I have flagged comments as obsolete, especially when the comment thread has gotten long and it is referring edits made to the post and there has been successful edits.

In the past I have flagged only the last message, only the first message, both the first and the last, and as many as five throughout the tread.

What would the moderators prefer?

Comment: You can also flag the *post* if there's a lot of cleanup to be done...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, I'm speaking only for myself, but I believe this is true of the other mods too.

In general, **it doesn't matter**. Usually, I look at the whole comment chain, and if there are other comments worthy of deletion, then we'll delete those too. This goes for unconstructive and chatty comments too.

Comment: Agreed.  Just draw our attention to it, and we can work it out.