# What makes a comment obsolete?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

This question is difference than [Guidelines on flagging obsolete comments](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/guidelines-on-flagging-obsolete-comments).

In this question I want to know what exactly makes a comment obsolete. I was looking through my flag history and noticed that the only declines I have are on obsolete comments.

When should I flag a comment as obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

I use it for anything that's been taken care of with an edit. I don't flag obsolete comments very often but when I have I think they've all been accepted. Got any specific examples of what was declined?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I flagged [this one](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15358/why-are-the-wicked-resurrected-only-to-be-destroyed-and-sent-to-the-lake-of-fire/15361#comment80236_15361) by you actually and the one below it by FMS. Both were declined. without a comment given. I think that's it really.

Comment: I do have obsolete flags that are helpful, I'm noticing now, so maybe I'm making a big deal out of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be too obvious, but it's for when a comment is no longer needed, typically because the question or answer was edited.

For example, an answer that originally cited no references, if someone commented pointing this out, and the post was edited to fix, the comment would then be obsolete.

The same might go for a question that was off-topic. Someone comments, question get fixed, the comment is now obsolete.